# Error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Read-only file system

Tags: git

I installed `git` after setting up Ubuntu 18.04.
I run `git fetch` with my old project, I got `Error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Read-only file system`. Before that, everything was ok
Thanks for any helps

Comment: Hint: The error is about the repository into which you want to fetch commits.

Comment: I tried to fetch with many repository, but I still got that message

Comment: The problem has very likely nothing to do with Git. Try to create a new file in the repository into which you are fetching. Do you get the same error? For example: `echo hello > hello.txt`

Comment: You're right. I got `zsh: read-only file system: hello.txt`

Comment: You might be better off asking on super-user.

Comment: Yah, I did @evolutionxbox

Comment: Moral of the story: *Actually listen to the error message. It might be telling you something.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error comes from my partition. I install dual-boot Window 10 and Ubuntu, turning on fast startup on Window 10 make partition can't unmount, and when I switch to Ubuntu, OS make partition mount read-only.

I try to run command

`ntfsfix /dev/sda5`

`umount /dev/sda5`

`mount /dev/sda5`

and it worked. Moreover, I turned of fast startup on Window 10

Answer (score 0):

i think best and safe option is to clone again the repo